# How to suppress: Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types

Tags: kotlin, inline

How to suppress the following warning?

> Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22844/Make-warning-Expected-performance-impact-for-inline-configurable):

```
@file:Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
```

or

```
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
```